# Height of the WPF window is not getting changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have wpf window in that I have taken rowdefinition and its height in designer is zero. Now in that window there is one button and in button click event I change the height of the rowdefition dynamically thus height of the window is changed. But after run the application if I dragged that window and click on that button then height of the window cannot be changed dynamically. But if I don't drag the window then height of the window can be changed, what the problem can be in the dragging window scenario ?

These are the properties I have set for the window.

```
MinWidth="400"  CanDrag="True" ShowStatusBar="False" CanResize="True"
```

RowDefinition in designer:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="rowMapping" Height="0"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This is how I change the height of the rowdefinition in code behind.

```
rowMapping.Height = new GridLength(420);
```

Comment: Show minimal code-behind and XAML, please.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue and I don't know the exact reason why this happened.But by setting Grid.Row/Colomn definitions height or width dynamically solved my issue.Hope this solves your's also.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefName" MinHeight="200" />                
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Code behind:

```
RowDefName.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Star);or   
RowDefName.Height = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto);or
RowDefName.Height = new GridLength(300, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```

And the control is placed at this row.

Comment: I have a spitter and a control above that and below that.If I move splitter then height property even after setting it didn't changed.Then I used the above code to change height of all 3 controls and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting `SizeToContent="Height"` property of the Window. I would also try setting height of the RowDefinition to auto and then giving a height to its content such as a grid.